# Decrypt a column data in Java side

Tags: java, sql, encryption

I have a column which is stored in encrypted format in database. In java code I am writing a query which will take that column in "order by " clause. Please guide me how to do that.

Example - Select * from table_1 where column_1 = abc order by column_2

Here column_2 is stored in encrypted format in Db. But I want to decrypt it while I am handling this query through my java code.

Comment: What you are trying to do will have severe performance implications: Your DB server will have to decrypt all encrypted values in the requested rows in order to sort them and no index can be used for this process.

Comment: @TasosP. not exactly. There is an order-preserving encryption (OPE) by Bolderiva. One can compare the encrypted values. The MIT's CryptDB (Popa et. al) already used this together with the Paillier encryption for aggregation. It must be note that one must carefully examine the queries so that they don't leak any information.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @kelalaka, I wasn't aware of OPE. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which SQL management system you are using it varies.

Here are the steps for SQL server assuming you have column level encryption:

In a query window, open the symmetric key used to encrypt the column. If the key is encrypted you will also need to decrypt that.

```
 OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_test
            DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test;
```

Use the SELECT statement and decrypt encrypted data using the DecryptByKey() function.

```
    SELECT Column_1, Column_2 AS 'Encrypted data',
                CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(Column_2)) AS 'Decrypted Column'
                FROM dbo.database;
Where foo = bar
order by Column_2
```